# Problem with UART communication with a Pepperl & Fuchs UCC4000 ultrasonic sensor

Tags: arduino, stm32, sensor, uart, distance

I have a problem with a Pepperl & Fuchs UCC4000 ultrasonic sensor. This sensor communicates with UART protocol and has data transmit - receive based a kind of checksum encoding. According to what it says in the datasheet, when I send four bytes of address learning (0xa8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x43) data over the UART, it should send me two bytes of data as a reply (sensor address, checksum byte.) My problem is that I do not the address info from the sensor.

```C
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    
    #define MAX_BYTES 20  SoftwareSerial ucc4000(12, 13); //Rx, Tx
    
    byte Get_Sensor_AdressCast[MAX_BYTES] = {0XA8, 0X00, 0X00, 0X43}; //To get sensor address. byte sensor_response[MAX_BYTES]; int numBytes = 0;
    
    void setup() {
         Serial.begin(19200);   ucc4000.begin(19200);    }
    
    void loop() { 
         ucc4000.write(Get_Sensor_AdressCast, MAX_BYTES);   delay(500);
         if (ucc4000.available() > 0) {
        while (ucc4000.available() && numBytes < MAX_BYTES) {
          sensor_response[numBytes] = ucc4000.read();
          numBytes++;
        }
        
        // print the received bytes
        Serial.print("Received bytes: ");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numBytes; i++) {
          if(sensor_response[i] != 0XFF)
          {
            Serial.print(sensor_response[i], HEX);
            Serial.print(" ");
          }
        }
        
        Serial.println();
        
        delay(500);   } }
```

Comment: what does this mean? ...  `I do not the address info from the sensor.` ... you do not what?

Comment: please copy the content of the serial monitor and add it to your question ... format it as code so that it is legible  .. also, please correct the indent levels of your code ... right now it is difficult to read

Comment: Well, if it does not respond, how do you know the command is sent properly? Or if the sensor is even listening for the correct interface? Or if software serial can do 19200? Too little info to debug.